# What's the point of having a constructor with a default argument that takes a user-defined type?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, stl

Ok so I'm trying to reimplement the Vector class from the STL. Here's a small chunk of the Template Class that includes a simple typedef for the Allocator passed as an argument.

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class vector {
public:
    typedef Allocator                                   allocator_type;
    // Other typedefs...
}
```

Simple  enough, however, I just can't wrap my head around this constructor:

```
explicit vector(const allocator_type &alloc = allocator_type());
```

What is ***allocator_type()*** referring to? Is it the typedef? Is this some kind of function call? Is it even possible to pass a user-defined type here? I'm probably just missing something.

Comment: It's referring to the default constructor of `allocator_type`. The `vector` expects a const reference to an allocator instance. If none is given the default value `allocator_type()` is used instead which provides a default constructed allocator instance. (Due to the default value for the one and only parameter this constructor of `vector` provides the default constructor for `vector` as well.)

Comment: @Simonechebelnome Did any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the `typedef`.

The class template parameter `Allocator` has a default type, `std::allocator<T>`. If that is used or not isn't important. What is important is that whatever type `Allocator` is, it gets a type alias in form of `allocator_type`.

The constructor has a default value which is a default constructed `allocator_type` (whatever type that is). You could supply an instance of an `allocator_type` (possibly not default constructed) to the constructor and it would use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `allocator_type` is an alias for the `Allocator`.
They mean the same thing but `Allocator` is only visible to members of the class, so the alias is required to make it `public`.

The constructor you've found would be an equivalent to:

```
explicit vector(const Allocator &alloc = Allocator());
```

except this notation is more confusing to the user of the class who can only use the name `allocator_type` in their code.

`= allocator_type()` just tells the compiler that it is an optional argument. If the user don't provide any other `allocator_type` object to the constructor of the `vector`, the default constructor of the `Allocator`/`allocator_type` will be used to create an object to be passed there instead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the underlying question: what's the point of this constructor? It's a special kind of default constructor. SFINAE (Subsitution Failure Is Not An Error) means that this is *not* a default constructor for `vector` when `Allocator` is not default-constructible. It's still usable as a normal constructor, though.